# Video and audio gradually desyncs in browser

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, browser, internet-explorer

Edit: After a suggestion from Xen2050 I found out that it's probably because of my wireless headset. Now I only need to find out how to fix the problem.

This is what happens with every video I watch:

The video is fine at the beginning, but after watching for a few minutes the video and audio is out of sync... and it gets worse the longer I watch. I can refresh the page and go back to the point where I left off, but then the audio slowly desyncs again.

In order to fix this I tried a couple of things:

- Watch videos on a different browser.
- Disable flash player in the Chrome plugins menu.
- Update flash player.

Some other things to note:

- This doesn't happen with a local .Avi file for example.
- This doesn't happen while playing games.
- This only happens on my desktop and not on other devices, so I doubt that my internet has something to do with it.
- It's the audio that I hear first and then the video catches up (so for example: I first hear someone talking, and then I see the person talking afterwards).
- I saw someone with similar problems that used a wireless headset, so do I. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Pc specs:

- OS: Windows 8.1
- CPU: Intel Core i5 4670 @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: 8GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. G1.Sniper B5-CF
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770 (MSI)
- Screen (just in case): BenQ DL2215 (1920x1080@60Hz)
- Wireless headset: Corsair Vengeance 2100 Headset

Anyway, I would really like to fix this problem because it's getting quite annoying. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Right click the video and do the "stats for nerds" and check for dropped frames, as one of the things available to see.  What is the complete path that your audio takes?  Specs of the computer? Audio device? settings? Type of outputs?  if headphone items,  are they digital USB or analog 3.5 stereo plug type? Bluetooth? wireless etc? And all your net stats, modem type, speed your supposed to get?

Comment: @Psycogeek I added my specs above, and here's some of the other info you asked for: 

- Dropped frames: 18/7221 after 5 minutes on Youtube.
- Audio device: Corsair Vengeance 2100 Headset. It has a USB tranceiver plugged into a USB 2.0 port (with a extension cable in between).
- Download speed is 9.5Mbps, upload is 0.82 Mbps. There's still a couple things that you asked for but, I can't answer those right now.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing happen with different video websites. It used to happen on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) pretty often too, but they updated their site somehow and fixed it, though I remember seeing it on some old videos as recently as earlier this year ('15). I *think* it's related more to the video format than to anything on your (client) end.

You could try using a browser addon ([Video Download Helper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) seems to work well) or other program / website to download the video to your computer first, and then try playing it outside a web browser with a program like [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). If it still has sync problems in vlc than you can confidently say that your web browser is not the problem (unless your browser just opens vlc and plays it in a browser window, but even that points the finger away from the browser itself).

Comment: Downloading the video could be a solution, but that's still not the result I'm looking for. And I doubt that it's related to the format of the video. If I watch the same video on my laptop there's nothing wrong, but on my desktop it desyncs...

Comment: Not a permanent solution, but could be a definitive test of the browser vs video player. And does it still happen with wired headset or speakers, *no* wireless sound?

Comment: I just tested a wired headset and it looks like the delay is gone. Now I know that my wireless headset is the problem... I just have to find out how to fix it.